# Codeigniter inserts partial CSV data into MYSQL only id and date

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, csv

Hi i am trying to insert data into mysql table by uploading the CSV. But i am getting an error. the upload shows me error and inserts only the id and date. I dont know the possible reasons for it. Firstly i exported the users table from MYSQL to csv format. Now i upload same using my code but does not work Below is my code :

I did Print_r($file_data);
so got this

```
Array ( [file_name] => users_(2)3.csv [file_type] => text/plain [file_path] => /var/www/Test/uploads/ [full_path] => /var/www/Test/uploads/users_(2)3.csv [raw_name] => users_(2)3 [orig_name] => users_(2).csv [client_name] => users (2).csv [file_ext] => .csv [file_size] => 3.83 [is_image] => [image_width] => [image_height] => [image_type] => [image_size_str] => )
```

The Controller :

```
    function importcsv() {
    $data['users'] = $this->csv_m->get_users();
    $data['error'] = '';    //initialize image upload error array to empty


    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'csv';
    $config['max_size'] = '1000';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);


    // If upload failed, display error
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {
        $data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
        print_r($_FILES);

        $this->load->view('csv', $data);
    } else {


        $file_data = $this->upload->data();
        $file_path =  './uploads/'.$file_data['file_name'];

        if ($this->csvimport->get_array($file_path))
         {
            $csv_array = $this->csvimport->get_array($file_path);

            foreach ($csv_array as $row)
             {
                $insert_data = array(

                    'id'=>$row['id'],
                    'sip_id'=>$row['sip_id'],
                    'sip_pass'=>$row['sip_pass'],
                    'key'=>$row['key'],
                    'name'=>$row['name'],
                    'status'=>$row['status'],
                    'email'=>$row['email'],
                    'password'=>$row['password'],
                    'phone'=>$row['phone'],
                    'balance'=>$row['balance'],
                    'created'=>$row['created'],
                    'modified'=>$row['modified'],
                    'date_inactive'=>$row['date_inactive'],
                    'reset_date'=>$row['reset_date'],


                );

                print_r($file_data);

                $this->csv_m->insert_csv($insert_data);
            }
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Csv Data Imported Succesfully');
            redirect(base_url().'csv');
            //echo "<pre>"; print_r($insert_data);
        } else 
            $data['error'] = "Error occured";
            $this->load->view('csv', $data);
        }


    }
```

The Model :

```
<?php

class Csv_m extends CI_Model {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

}

function get_users() {     
    $query = $this->db->get('users');

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
     {
        return $query->result_array();
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo"Nothing To Show";
        return FALSE;
    }
}

function insert_csv($data) {
    $this->db->insert('users', $data);
}
```

}

The View :

```
   <?php if (isset($error)): ?>
            <div class="alert alert-error"><?php echo $error; ?></div>
        <?php endif; ?>


        <h2>CI Addressbook Import</h2>
            <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url() ?>csv/importcsv" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" name="userfile" ><br><br>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="UPLOAD" class="btn btn-primary">
            </form>

        <br><br>
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
            <caption>Address Book List</caption>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>SIP Id</th>
                    <th>SIP Password</th>
                    <th>Key</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Password</th>
                    <th>Balance</th>
                    <th>Created</th>
                    <th>Modified</th>
                    <th>Date_Inactive</th>
                    <th>Date Reset</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php if ($users == FALSE): ?>
                    <tr><td colspan="4">There are currently Users</td></tr>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <?php foreach ($users as $row): ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['sip_id']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['sip_pass']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['key']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['status']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['password']; ?></td>
                             <td><?php echo $row['phone']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['balance']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['created']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['modified']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['date_inactive']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['reset_date']; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Please Review my code and help me solve this issue. When i upload the csv i get an error :

> Message: Undefined index: id
>   Message: Undefined index: sip_id
>   Message: Undefined index: sip_pass

and all other fields. But some how id and date get inserted in table and other fields dont!

The Error I face :
[image: Error]

Comment: check in views `if(!empty($users)){ foreach ($users as $row):}`

Comment: shall i change that to this?

Comment: yes because  if `return FALSE;` from your model it means your `$users` array are empty

Comment: <?php if(!empty($users)){ foreach ($users as $row):} ?> is this right?

Comment: and i get this else portion from model code :Nothing To Show

Comment: @Saty can you tell me where i am wrong

Comment: use `<?php if (!empty($users)): ?>` instead `<?php if ($users == FALSE): ?>`

Comment: @Saty  now it says Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: @Saty please post this an answer so i can also accept your answer and help others also

Comment: also i have update the question code i have printed the file_data's output please verify that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Message: Undefined index: id Message: Undefined index: sip_id Message: Undefined index: sip_pass

this error occurs when variable is not define or no data related with it

Make sure your `$users` array names are with this names

```
$row['id'];
$row['sip_id'];
$row['sip_pass'];
$row['key'];
$row['name'];
$row['status'];
$row['email'];
$row['password'];
$row['phone'];
$row['balance'];
$row['created'];
$row['modified'];
$row['date_inactive'];
$row['reset_date'];
```

and in view table should be

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
    <caption>Address Book List</caption>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>SIP Id</th>
        <th>SIP Password</th>
        <th>Key</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Password</th>
        <th>Balance</th>
        <th>Created</th>
        <th>Modified</th>
        <th>Date_Inactive</th>
        <th>Date Reset</th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php if (empty($users)) //use empty()
    {
        ?>
        <tr><td colspan = "4" > There are currently Users </td ></tr>
    <?php
    }
    else
    {
        foreach ($users as $row)
        {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['sip_id']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['sip_pass']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['key']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['status']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['password']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['phone']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['balance']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['created']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['modified']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['date_inactive']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['reset_date']; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php
        }
    }
    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and in model

```
function get_users() {
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    $result = $query->result_array();

    $count = count($result);

    if (empty($count))
    {
        return $result;
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your model `return false` the user $users array is empty. So in view you have you check empty

```
<?php if (!empty($users)): ?>// check empty array
    <tr><td colspan="4">There are currently Users</td></tr>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php foreach ($users as $row): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['sip_id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['sip_pass']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['key']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['status']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['password']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['phone']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['balance']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['created']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['modified']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['date_inactive']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['reset_date']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: hi this solve the empty array error but still i get the error in my controller or the model that undefined id,sip_id,sip_pass,key..............

Comment: Also the data is not getting imported in mysql

Comment: `print_r( $csv_array)` and paste the valus of it

Comment: i get an array of my database values of each records

Comment: `$csv_array = $this->csvimport->get_array($file_path);print_r( $csv_array)`

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [1] => 2 [I am here2] => 011123 [00] => 02 [XYZ- 91-100-2] => Hiren-+91-100-2 [XYZ Soni] => XYZ [active] => active [XYZ@yahoo.com] => XYZ@yahoo.com [3d45ac38d414bc19bdaa35bb40e90ff5d0f5b82efd1e8727c0c5a0e8941ac1e3c2548b9dae5d44d4e638c901daf6d36dd16aae4a25c84d71ea623c8cf9db8d36] =>

Comment: i get an array like this

Comment: AS you see there is no `id,key sip_id` in your array and that is the cause of error

Comment: Check your csv file if `id,key sip_id` are not there try to put there value. And now you understand where is the problem. first correct your csv file and you correct your code

Comment: i exported the users table as CSV and got only the data and not the fields name. Now if i edit the csv its extension get changed :(

Comment: what could be the possible solution to this as my csv file is exported by PHPMYADMIN and returns only data and no column name